Nimble Code for Time and Sex effet on survival and detection probability
We have a data frame in R from capture-mark-recapture data.
set.seed(123)
n <- 111
years <- 1997:2004
year_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, n * length(years), 
                  replace = TRUE), nrow = n, ncol = length(years)))
names(year_data) <- years

sex <- sample(1:2, n, replace = TRUE)
oxy <- round(runif(n, min = 120, max = 160), 1)

seagull <- data.frame(year_data, sex = sex, oxy = oxy)

head(seagull)

<!-- end snippet -->

We wanted to see how sex and time affect survival and detection probability. We applied the time effect on detection probability and the sex effect on survival probability, but don't know how to combine them.
This is how we modeled it.
y <- seagull[, 2:9]

# Number of occasions

T <- ncol(y)

# Find the occasion when the seagull was first contacted

first <- apply(y, 1, function(x) min(which(x !=0)))
first

SEX <- seagull$sex
SEX 
summary(SEX )
maxsex <- max(SEX )
maxsex
minsex <- min(SEX )
minsex
nsex <- maxsex - minsex + 1
nsex
sex <- SEX

zinits <- function(y) {
  T <- length(y)
  first <- min(which(y != 0))
  last <- max(which(y == 1))
  z <- rep(NA, T)
  if(last == T) {
    z[first:T] <- 1
  } else {
    if(last == (T - 1)) {
      z[first:(T - 1)] <- 1
      z[T] <- sample(1:2, size = 1)
    } else {
      death <- sample((last + 1):T, size = 1)
      z[first:(death - 1)] <- 1
      z[death:T] <- 2
    }
  }
  return(z)
}

nobs <- sum(apply(y, 1, sum) != 0)
nobs

for (i in 1:nobs){
  if(first[i] > 1) y[i, 1:(first[i]-1)] <- NA
}

my.data <- list(y = y + 1)

z <- t(apply(y, 1, zinits))
p = runif(T-1, 0, 1)
beta = rnorm(nsex, 0, 1)

initial.values <- list(beta = beta,
                       p = p,
                       z =  z)

my.constants <- list(N = nrow(y),      # nb of individuals
                     T = ncol(y),      # nb of occasions
                     first = first,    # occasions of first capture
                     sex = sex, # pod size
                     nsex = nsex
)    
my.constants

# the model
hmm.phipodgroup.pt <- nimbleCode({
  delta[1] <- 1          # Pr(alive t = 1) = 1
  delta[2] <- 0          # Pr(dead t = 1) = 0
  
  for (g in 1:nsex){ # priors on pod size as group
    beta[g] ~ dnorm(T-1, sd = 1.5)
  }
  
  for (i in 1: N){
    logit(phi[i]) <- beta[sex[i]]
    gamma[1,1,i] <- phi[i]      # Pr(alive t -> alive t+1)
    gamma[1,2,i] <- 1 - phi[i]  # Pr(alive t -> dead t+1)
    gamma[2,1,i] <- 0        # Pr(dead t -> alive t+1)
    gamma[2,2,i] <- 1        # Pr(dead t -> dead t+1)
  }
  
  for (t in 1:(T-1)){
    
    p[t] ~ dunif(0, 1) # prior detection
    
    omega[1,1,t] <- 1 - p[t]    # Pr(alive t -> non-detected t)
    omega[1,2,t] <- p[t]        # Pr(alive t -> detected t)
    omega[2,1,t] <- 1        # Pr(dead t -> non-detected t)
    omega[2,2,t] <- 0        # Pr(dead t -> detected t)
  }
  
  # likelihood
  for (i in 1:N){
    z[i,first[i]] ~ dcat(delta[1:2])
    for (j in (first[i]+1):T){
      z[i,j] ~ dcat(gamma[z[i,j-1], 1:2,  i])
      y[i,j] ~ dcat(omega[z[i,j], 1:2,  j-1])
    }
  }
})

parameters.to.save <- c("p", "beta")

n.iter <- 5000
n.burnin <- 2000
nc <- 4
nt <- 4

output.orca <- nimbleMCMC(code = hmm.phipodgroup.pt, # model code 
                          constants = my.constants,  # constants
                          data = my.data,            # data
                          inits = initial.values,    # initial values
                          monitors = parameters.to.save,     
    # parameters to monitor
                          niter = n.iter,      # nb of iterations
                          nburnin = n.burnin,  
    # length of the burn-in period
                          nchains = nc,        # nb of chains
                          summary = TRUE, WAIC=TRUE)

MCMCsummary(output.orca$samples, round = 4)

MCMCplot(output.orca$samples)

MCMCplot(output.orca$samples, params=c('beta'))

MCMCtrace(output.orca$samples, pdf=FALSE, ind=TRUE)

output.orca$WAIC$WAIC

How can we make this model show both effects on each variable?
